# Segmentation Fault on sort

Tags: c, arrays

When sorting an array using an algorithm called tubor sort, i implemented it and when i ran it i get segmentation fault. Even though i searched the net and there where no similar errors, i decided to post here. This error could have been because i set the size of aux array in the for loop to the size of array, is there a better way of writing this code? Below is the source.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void TuborSort(int* array) {
  int aux[5] = { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
    aux[array[i]]++;
  }

  int j = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    while(aux[i]-- > 0) {
      array[j++] = i;
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  int array[6] = {2, 5, 1, 4, 1};
  int i;

  TuborSort(array);

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++)
    printf("%d ", array[i]);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: size of array is 6 ... size of aux is 5

Comment: `int* array` -> sizeof(array) //as pointer size

Comment: 7 downvotes ?!! Why ?

Comment: Good question @cnicutar i don't know something i asked and alot of discouragement except you though thanks a lot. its working now

Comment: "turbo" sort ? Sounds like a counting- or histogram- sort..

Comment: Guys tell me what was wrong with my post that i got too many down votes, so i can fix it! I have been banned because of this post..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're saying `aux[array[i]]++` and aux is only 5 elements long. So **the second element in `array` (5) is too big** to be used as an index for `aux`.

---

As a side note, the way you're using `sizeof` is wrong, you need to pass the length of the array as an additional parameter.

As Alexey notes, in `main` the for should be:

```
size_t i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array); i++)
```

Comment: The side note is rather critical

Comment: `sizeof` is wrong in both places.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze Good call, I hadn't noticed the second `sizeof`.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(array)` in your `TuborSort()` function is not appropriate. As you have declared `array` is `int *` and not array of 6 integers, which is not what you want.

Also, instead of `sizeof` you want count of elements in the array, which is `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])`.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very common error for people who knows Java, the pointer in c and c++ is of a size derived from the Architecture usually 32/64 bits on PC.

once you pass a pointer to array you must send its length, otherwise you **can't** know what its length.

Comment: 32/64 bits -- says who?

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze added usually